# A short KenKen solver

Tags: beginner, haskell, sudoku

I'm new to Haskell and I've made a very short [KenKen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KenKen) solver. Any input is welcome.

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

set :: [Int] -> Bool
set x = x == nub x

mats :: Int -> [[[Int]]]
mats x = filter (all set . transpose) . replicateM x $ permutations [1 .. x]

doIt :: Int -> [([(Int, Int)], [Int] -> Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
doIt n blocks = join . take 1 . foldl' (flip filter) (mats n) $ map bfun blocks

revSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
revSort = sortBy $ flip compare

quotient :: [Int] -> Int
quotient = foldl1 div . revSort

sub :: [Int] -> Int
sub = foldl1 (-) . revSort

bfun :: ([(Int, Int)], [Int] -> Int, Int) -> [[Int]] -> Bool
bfun (locs, opp, res) mat = res == opp (map (\ (x, y) -> mat !! x !! y) locs)

sampleBlocs :: [([(Int, Int)], [Int] -> Int, Int)]
sampleBlocs = [([(0, 0), (1, 0)], quotient, 2),
               ([(0, 1), (1, 1)], sub, 1),
               ([(0, 2)], sum, 1),
               ([(2, 0), (2, 1)], sub, 2),
               ([(1, 2), (2, 2)], product, 6)]

sampleBlocs2 :: [([(Int, Int)], [Int] -> Int, Int)]
sampleBlocs2 = [([(0, 0), (0, 1)],         sub,      2),
                ([(1, 0)],                 sum,      4),
                ([(2, 0), (2, 1)],         quotient, 2),
                ([(3, 0), (3, 1)],         sub,      1),
                ([(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2)], product,  8),
                ([(2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3)], sum,      8),
                ([(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)], sum,      6)]

-- doIt 3 sampleBlocs == [[2,3,1],[1,2,3],[3,1,2]]
-- doIt 4 sampleBlocs2 == [[1,3,4,2],[4,1,2,3],[2,4,3,1],[3,2,1,4]]
```

Comment: It's been almost four years since you've asked this question. Maybe you want to review your own code?